# Sharepoint 2013 счетчик просмотра видео

Tags: sharepoint

К SharePoint 2013 подключен SilverLight для просмотра видео, не работает счетчик.
Где и как его можно проверить?

Comment: `не работает счетчик?` — это вы должны знать, работает ли у вас счётчик.

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили опечатку, ну да я согласен легче придираться к знакам препинания, чем ответить на данный вопрос.